# An easy way with Twitter API to get the list of Followings for a very large list of users?

Tags: ruby, twitter

I have about 200,000 Twitter followers across a few twitter accounts. I am trying to find the twitter accounts that a large proportion of my followers are following.

Having looked over the Search API I think this is going to be very slow, unless I am missing a something.

40 calls using [GET followers/ids](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/friends/ids) to get the list of 200,000 accounts. Then all I can think of is doing 200,000 calls to [GET friends/ids](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/friends/ids). But at the current rate limit of 150 calls/hour, that would take 55 days. Even if I could get Twitter to up my limit slightly, this is still going to be slow going. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is, no, there is indeed no quick way to do this. And furthermore, with API v 1.0 being deprecated sometime in March, and v 1.1 being the law of the land (more on this in a moment).

As I understand it, what you want to do is compile a list of followed accounts for each of the initial 200,000 follower accounts. You then want to count each one of these 200,000 original accounts as a "voter", and then the total set of accounts followed by any of these 200,000 as "candidates".  Ultimately, you want to be able to rank this list of candidates by "votes" from the list of 200,000.

A few things:

1.) I believe you're actually referencing the [REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1), not the Search API.

2.) Based on what you've said about getting 150 requests per hour, I can infer that you're making unauthenticated requests to the API endpoints in question. That limits you to only 150 calls. As a short term fix (i.e., in the next few weeks, prior to v 1.0 being retired), you could make authenticated requests instead, which will boost your hourly rate limit to 350 (source: [Twitter API Documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting#rest)).  That alone would more than double your calls per hour.

2.) If this is something you expect to need to do on an ongoing basis, things get much worse.  Once API 1.0 is no longer available, you'll be subject to the v 1.1 API limits, which a.) require authentication, no matter what, and b.) are limited per API method/endpoint. For GET friends/ids and GET followers/ids, in particular, you will be able to only make **15 calls per 15 minutes** or **60 per hour**.  That means that the sort of analysis you want to do will basically become unfeasible (unless you were to skirt the Twitter API terms of service by using multiple apps/ip addresses, etc.). You can read all about this [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1).  Suffice to say, researchers and developers that rely on these API endpoints for doing network analysis are less than happy about these changes, but Twitter doesn't appear to be moderating its position on this.

Given all of the above, my best advice would be to use API version 1.0 while you still can, and start making authenticated requests.

Another thought -- not sure what your use case is -- but you might consider pulling in, say, the 1000 most recent tweets from each of the 200,000 followers and then leveraging the metadata contained in each tweet about mentions. Mentions of other users are potentially more informative than knowing that someone simply follows someone else. You could still tally the most mentioned accounts. The benefit here would be that in moving from API 1.0 to 1.1, the endpoint for pulling in timelines for users will actually have it's API limit raised from 350 per hour to 720 (Source: [Twitter API 1.1 documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline))

Hope this helps, and good luck!

Ben

Comment: Awesome response! The use-case is for a publication that wants to identify celebrities/musicians/brands that its followers are interested in, that it doesn't yet know about. Will help them produce articles relevant to their followers